# Can't scroll page with space bar after page finished loading

Tags: google-chrome

With one website I use (pixiv.net) via Chrome, I can scroll the pages down by by pressing space *until* the page finished loading.  After it finishes loading I can scroll using the arrow keys and the PageDown/PageUp keys, but not space.  If I hit `Tab` twice then the page starts responding to space again, but that causes the tab to jump down to the very bottom of the page.  This behavior persists even if I disable both extensions and experiments.

I have the [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/) extension installed and know how to use it, but before I can use it to fix this behaviour I need to know what the page it doing to cause this behaviour, or at least know how to diagnose/debug the problem.

**EDIT**: Clearing the cache doesn't help.

I've written a TamperMonkey script which adds event listeners for `DomContentLoaded` and `load`.  The original intent was to have them put the focus back onto an element in the page, however, it seems that regardless of what the event listener functions do, it fixes the problem 80% of the time (that is, explicitly putting the focus onto an element of the page doesn't hep 20% of the time, and only putting in a debug statement to write to the console works 80% of the time).  I'm wondering if maybe this is some timing/race problem.

**EDIT 2**: Clearing all pixiv.net cookies doesn't fix the problem either.

I've tested with Chrome version 64.0.3278.0 (unstable) and the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when the problem arises, it's due to one of the `iframe`s stealing the focus from the parent/top document (as revealed by entering `document.activeElement` into the JavaScript console).  I'm guessing that some of the ads served up in the `iframe`s steal focus while others don't, so it's the randomness in the ads which causes the problem to be intermittent.

Answer (score 0):

I went to pixiv and scrolled on several pages, during and after loading, using Chrome.  I'm on Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit). I had no problem scrolling with the mouse, page up/dn, arrows or the spacebar.

Check if Chrome is up to date on your computer. Also, clear your history to start fresh.

Comment: Clearing history won't do anything to help. Clearing the cache might ...

Comment: I cleared the cache, didn't help.

Comment: And Chrome is up to date?  Have you tried another browser or another computer?  Yea, I'm asking silly tech support questions, but I couldn't replicate the problem so I'm thinking you need to try to determine what is different about your particular setup.